# When I use fileId from shared drive webhook do not come, although endpoint returns status 200

Tags: google-drive-api

I use endpoint: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch
When I use fileId from shared drive webhook do not come, although endpoint returns status 200.

**Example request:**
post https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/watch?supportsAllDrives=true&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&driveId=driveId&corpora=allDrives

```
{"json":
       {
        "id":"639a6aa3-7fd5-453d-a6bc-0e23cc18ae5a",
        "type":"web_hook",
        "address":"webhook_url"
        },
 "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer access_token"}
}
```

**Response:**

```
{ 
 "kind":"api#channel", 
 "id":"23b19957-02c8-4d0a-ae0e-4df212aa7be2",
 "resourceId":"h10uxtg5-JHzbj6J72tyUQoqq2w",
 "resourceUri":"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/drive\/v3\/files\/fileId?acknowledgeAbuse=false&supportsAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=false&alt=json",
 "expiration":"1629802124000"
}
```

When I use fileId from default drive webhook come, request and response are the same as described above.
What is the problem and what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How are you receiving the notifications? Did you set up your channel correctly? Do you have access to this file? Please bear in mind that notifications might experience some delay as well.